# How do I build an array of names gathered from a text file which correspond to an array of links gathered from the same file?

Tags: arrays, parsing, text, hyperlink, names

I need to create an array of names which correspond to links to images which I have stored in another array.  Both the names and links to images are found in the same text file, and the links to images follow their corresponding names in the file.  I build the array of image links by parsing the text file using the following code:

```
import re
images = []
with open('html_test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        images.extend(re.findall(r'"([^"]*\.(?:jpg|gif)[^"]*)"',line))
```

Using a similar method I could build a list of names, if there were only one name per image link.  Unfortunately the number of image links following each name is variable, some names are followed by only one image link, some are followed by many.

What I think I need to do is count how many links to images follow each name, then create duplicate entries in the name array for each name which is followed by more then one image.  (the number of duplicate name entries per name would be equal to the number of image links which follow each name minus 1.)  When I try to do this however, all I get is a count of the total number of names in the entire text file.  Does anybody know how to go about building an array of names so that each name is entered into the array once for each link to an image file which follows it? (except for those which follow the next name in the text file)

Below is an example of what the text file looks like:

```
<a href="/admin/user/view/41900" title="example_name_1" rel="41900">
<div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="https://jibbertyjob.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/1/5d4e6a0fjfe94980ny8en9uf98frnoad1876c00.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></div>
<a href="/admin/user/view/41900" title="example_name_2" rel="41900">
<div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="https://jibbertyjob.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/1/5d4e6a0fjfe9dfgsdfg9uf98frnoad1876l00.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="https://jibbertyjob.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/1/5d4e6a0fjf4567w034098h9h5fg4gr33r3rggr376c09940.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></div>
```

Thanks so much I've been stuck on this for half of the day!